# Getting CSS selector for Electron's web-frame

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

Is it possible to get a CSS selector for iframe/frame that is assigned to specified web-frame?
I know that it is possible to get web-frame knowing the iframe selector ([docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-frame.md#webframegetframeforselectorselector)), but it is possible to do the opposite?

Some code that illustrates what I would like to achieve:

```
webContents.on("did-frame-finish-load", (event, isMainFrame, frameProcessId, frameRoutingId) => {
     if (!isMainFrame) {
         const path = webFrame.findFrameByRoutingId(frameRoutingId).parent.getCssSelector(frameRoutingId)
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a reference to the element, you could also address its id and classes. From there, you can easily create CSS selectors.

Example for id:

```
function getCSSSelector(id){
    return "#" + id;
}
```

Comment: I do not have a reference to the element. I do only have frameProcessId and frameRoutingId. I do not have reference for any DOM object